# Using type hint annotation using types.FunctionType vs typing.Callable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

What are the drawbacks or benefits to using [types.FunctionType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#standard-interpreter-types) vs [typing.Callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#callable) as a type-hint annotation?

Consider the following code...

```
import types
import typing

def functionA(func: types.FunctionType):
    rt = func()
    print(func.__name__)
    return rt

def functionB(func: typing.Callable):
    rt = func()
    print(func.__name__)
    return rt
```

The only difference I can see is `Callable` could be any sort of callable object (function, method, class, etc) while `FunctionType` is limited to only functions.
Am I overlooking something?  Is there a benefit to using `FunctionType` over `Callable` in certain situations?

Comment: What does your function require? A callable object, or an instance of the type created by function definitions?

Comment: Declare whatever type matches your actual requirements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `types` module predates PEP 484 annotations and was created mostly to make runtime introspection of objects easier. For example, to determine if some value is a function, you can run `isinstance(my_var, types.FunctionType)`.

The `typing` module contains type hints that are specifically intended to assist static analysis tools such as mypy. For example, suppose you want to indicate that a parameter *must* be a function that accepts two ints and returns a `str`. You can do so like this:

```
def handle(f: Callable[[int, int], str]) -> None: ...
```

There is no way to use `FunctionType` in a similar manner: it simply was not designed for this purpose.

This function signature is also more flexible: it can also accept things like objects with a `__call__` since such objects are indeed callable.

The contents of the `typing` module can also sometimes be used for runtime checks in a manner similar to the contents of `types` as a convenience: for example, doing `isinstance(f, Callable)` works. However, this functionality is deliberately limited: doing `isinstance(f, Callable[[int, int], str])` is intentionally disallowed. Attempting to perform that check will raise an exception at runtime.

That said, I don't think it's a good style to perform runtime checks using anything from `typing`: the `typing` module is meant first and foremost for static analysis.

I would not use anything from the `types` module within type hints for similar reasons. The only exception is if your function is written in a way such that it's critical that the value you need to receive is specifically an instance of `FunctionType`, rather than being any arbitrary callable.

Comment: I agree that using typing for runtime is not a great idea.  I'm less convinced that using types in annotations is unwise.  The whole idea of them is to provide some clue as to what the argument _should_ be.  Why would FunctionType be any less of a hint?

Comment: @MarcelWilson -- Well, a type like `Callable[[int, int], str]` is going to be more descriptive and useful then just `FunctionType`. And as stated, the latter type is unnecessarily restrictive: it's not compatible with classes that define a `__call__` method. There are some cases where it's useful to have this distinction, but these cases are rare. And yes, using types in type hints is what you're supposed to do -- but using types from specifically the `types` module such as `FunctionType` will typically result in less precise signatures.

Comment: What about for `GeneratorType` which exists only in `types` but not in `typing`.  I would like to be able to indicate that a Generator is being returned, but can't do it with just `typing`.  Or am I missing something?